# Java Applet in JFrame image not Showing UP

Tags: java, image, swing, applet, jframe

I wrote this code in JFrame + Applet for a Game.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class myGame extends Applet {
    static myGame k = new myGame();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("myGame");
    URL url;
    Image player;

    public void init(){
        url = this.getDocumentBase();
        player = this.getImage(url,"as.jpeg");//Here is the Image import
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("HI THERE",200,200);
        g.fillRect(120,130,50,50);
        g.drawImage(player,20,200,this); Here I draw it
    }

    public void start(){
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(k);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        k.start();
    }
}
```

I cannot see the Image showing up as.jpg.
I wanted to Import this Image as a player sprite. My code is not giving any errors, it just not showing the image.

Comment: Where is getImage() API?

Comment: @AzeezNiazi Please improve your code formatting on your next questions

Comment: Dude Easy cant u see this is my first Question @StackOverFlow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You forget to call `init()` method of your Applet, because of your `Image` doesn't initialized.

2)Use `BufferedImage` for your image, load that like next:

```
public void init() {
    url = getClass().getResource("as.jpeg");
    try {
        player = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

3) add `k.init();` before `k.start();` in your `main` method.

Comment: Thanx for Replying I tried ur Way I had to import javax.imageio.*;
but the image is still not Showing Up??

Comment: where is yor image placed? Do you change your init method and call that before `start()`?

Comment: My image is in the same folder of .class file d:/java/JFrame
and yes I called k.init() before k.start();

Comment: When you run your program do you have any exceptions? Also you have image `as.jpeg` or `as.jpg`, validate that in classpath and in code ?

Comment: WOW!!! it just was as.jpg and not jpeg and i've been crying about the code any way thanx Thank U @alex2410